# Is there a site that allows timezone conversion on a given date easily by URL

Tags: url, time, timezone

I am looking for a timezone converter site which accepts arguments of a time, city, and date on the command line and opens up a page showing the equivalent time/date in my current locale. (Needing to specify my current locale would be acceptable.) I do need it to be a little smart about searching for the cities - I don't want to have to enter an exact timezone syntax but rather a substring which results in a unique search.

Unfortunately spending money is not an option - I've got to find a free service.

More detail:

I use [DTRT](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/DoTheRightThing) extensively and would love to be able to do an instant time zone conversion straight from my address bar.

I would like to type this:

3pm Dallas 2015-03-20

and get a page telling me what time that will be in my current location (and perhaps in certain other locations I would set up).

The DTRT is designed to simply convert the query string in the URL to a different URL so I'm looking for a site that might accept GET parameters like this in the URL. I've done quite a bit of googling, but so far everything I have found either (1) requires me to go through their interface to convert the cities to codes or (2) doesn't do GET parameters at all.

Any time zone converters you know that do this? The closest I've found is [this](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=My+Meeting&iso=20150320T15&p1=70) and it uses those codes...

[Here](http://www.thetimezoneconverter.com/?t=9:00%20am&tz=Dallas) is another option which works just by naming the city in the URL, but it has no capability of doing it for another date. When I am setting up meetings when one city changes to DST one week and another city 3 weeks later I absolutely have to have the date capability.

Comment: I note a couple down-votes on the question but no comment as to what is wrong with the question. If it deserves a down-vote, please let me know why so I won't do it again in the future...

Comment: Why don't you use their API? Otherwise you will definitely need some kind of list with cities/countries/timezones in order to do what you want. https://services.timeanddate.com/api/doc/srv-timeservice.html

Comment: Money is why I can't use their API. $80/year without any budget at all just doesn't work. :-(

Comment: I see. I have an idea. You could use google maps api, but I don't know what are the limitations. The idea is as follows: 1) Get coordinates of the city: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Dallas&sensor=false 2) By given coordinates get the timezone: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=32.7766642,-96.79698789999999&timestamp=1331161200&sensor=false 3) Save the time zone and the city (cache it for further usage) 4) Convert to this timezone

Comment: I could set up something fast (and maybe ugly) if you want based on the above idea, but I don't know if it will be helpful?

Comment: Not a downvoter, but per the close reasons, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow."  This question is off-topic, and will most likely be closed once the bounty expires (if it doesn't get flagged for moderator attention before then).

Comment: @littlebobbytables, you are right. I didn't read carefully enough. Since I already have a bounty up I will leave it, but I will avoid questions like this in the future now that you have made me aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wolfram alpha?

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3pm+Dallas+2015-03-20

Comment: This time it worked. I'll try again a few more times and find out if the server is reliable enough to be used - the functionality certainly fits the request.

Comment: Seems to be working fine now. I like that the order of the city/date/time is irrelevant and it just parses for all of them. This is my solution - THANKS!